# Geometric sum with square root

Tags: summation

What is the result of
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \sqrt t a^t ?$$

where $a \in (0,1)?$

**My effort:** The geometric sum writes
$$\forall a\in (0,1) \qquad \sum_{t=0}^\infty a^t = \frac{1}{1-a}$$
Informally, we can make the derivative of both sides having
$$\forall a\in (0,1) \qquad \sum_{t=0}^\infty (t+1)a^t = \frac{1}{(1-a)^2}$$
which entails $\sum_{t=0}^\infty ta^t = \frac{1}{(1-a)^2}-\frac{1}{1-a}$. Of course, this trick only works for integer powers, not for $\sqrt t$, but I suspect that
$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \sqrt t a^t \approx \frac{1}{(1-a)^{3/2}}$

Comment: See the [Lerch transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

Comment: Your sum is precisely $\operatorname{Li}_{-1/2}(a) $, a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), and so any further simplification is unlikely. You can try to take the [fractional half-derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_derivatives) of $1/(1-a)$ but this does not appear to yield the `correct' answer. In the special regime as $a \to 1$, it is true that  $\operatorname{Li}_{-1/2}(a) \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(1-a)^{3/2}}$

Comment: @Sal can you tell me how to get the last result? I am interested precisely in the case of $a\to 1$

Comment: @DavideMaran This is a gentle reminder to accept an answer if your question has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested. We have

$$
f(a)=\sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty t^{1/2}a^t=\operatorname{Li}_{-1/2}(a)
$$

Where $\operatorname{Li}$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). First, I plotted the ratio of $f(a)/(1-a)^{-3/2}$, since $(1-a)^{-3/2}$ was the conjectured behavior. As $a \to 1$ the result approached a finite number- great! Then I consulted the [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Asymptotic_expansions) wiki page and the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12). The useful expression is

$$\tag{ 25.12.12}
\operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)=\Gamma(1-s)(-\ln z)^{s-1}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\zeta(s-n)\frac{(\ln z)^n}{n!}
$$

Where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function, and $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. As $z\to 1$, $\ln z \to 0$, which means that  as long as $s-1<0$, the factor of $(-\ln z)^{s-1}$ will be large (going to inifnity) compared to any $(\ln z)^n$ (going to zero). The leading order behavior is then

$$
\operatorname{Li}_{-1/2}(a)\sim\Gamma(3/2)(-\ln a)^{-3/2} \qquad,\qquad a\to1
$$

Where I've set $z=a$ and $s=-1/2$. Then with $\Gamma(3/2)=\sqrt{\pi}/2$, and

$$
-\ln a\sim 1-a \qquad,\qquad a\to 1
$$

We have directly

$$
f(a)\sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(1-a)^{-3/2} \qquad,\qquad a\to 1
$$

Eq (25.12.12) furnishes the whole asymptotic series for $a\to 1$. For example, the three term series is

$$
f(a)\sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(1-a)^{-3/2} +\zeta(-1/2)+\zeta(-3/2)(a-1)\qquad,\qquad a\to 1
$$

Note that all terms after the second vanish when $a= 1$.

Aside: we may take the [fractional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_derivative_of_a_basic_power_function)

$$
D^{1/2}g(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x dx' \frac{g(x')}{\sqrt{x-x'}}
$$

of $g(x)=\sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty x^t=(1-x)^{-1}$. Formally, this yields

$$\tag{*}
\sqrt{\pi x} D^{1/2}g(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)}+\frac{\sqrt{x}\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})}{(1-x)^{3/2}}
$$

Which is not $\operatorname{Li}_{-1/2}$.The reason is that the fractional half derivative (in the sense above) doesn't pull out the $t^{1/2}$, in fact we have

$$
D^{1/2}x^t=\left[\frac{\Gamma(t+1)}{\Gamma(t+1/2)}\right]x^{t-1/2}\neq t^{1/2}x^{t-1/2}
$$

Consequently, eq (*) has not computed the sum $\sum\limits_t t^{1/2}x^t$, but another, similar sum. Interestingly, eq (*) does provide the same leading order behavior as $x\to 1$ as $\operatorname{Li}_{-1/2}$, which is; I suppose, because  $\frac{\Gamma(t+1)}{\Gamma(t+1/2)} \sim \sqrt{t}$ as $t\to \infty$, in fact the difference for all $t$ is very small.